# How can I use PWM channel and control its not channel enable\disable through code while runtime code in STM32?

Tags: timer, stm32, pwm

I want to drive a compliment switch using STM32F103.
sometimes these two switches are not a compliment and I should change the compliment state while the input voltage polarite change.

can you give me resources for compliment mode PWM generation of STM32 Timer or an example for it?